# Cannot make a simple page transition work with Barba js in a WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, barbajs

I’m developing a custom theme for WP and need to make page transitions similar to this website https://www.instrument.com/

[Barba.js](https://barba.js.org/) seems like a perfect solution for these purposes. However, the entire DOM tree always refreshes instead of just the content.

Here is what I have:

`header.php`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <?php wp_head();?>
  </head>
  <body data-barba="wrapper"
    <?php
      if ( get_field('is_dark_theme') ) {
        body_class( 'bg-dark text-light' );
      } else {
        body_class();
      }
      ?>
  >

  <nav>
    ...
  </nav>

  <main data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="home">
```

`footer.php`

```
    </main>
  </div>

  <?php wp_footer();?>

  </body>
</html>
```

In my main script file which is injected right before the closing of the body tag, I have the following:

```
(function () {
  barba.init({
    transitions: [{
      name: 'default-transition',
      leave() {
        console.log('leave');
      },
      enter() {
        console.log('enter');
      }
    }]
  });
})();
```

When I click on the link in the navbar, there is a `leave` console output but then the entire page is loaded again as if Barba was never there. I never see `enter` output.

Is it possible to use Barba with WP in the first place? If so, what am I doing wrong?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with [the default timeout](https://barba.js.org/docs/userguide/syntax/#timeout) in Barba. It was set to 2000ms and my pages took longer than that. If the page takes longer than the timeout, Barba gives up and the entire page refreshes.

I’ve set the timeout to a higher value and it works perfectly.